# "Merge branch main " appearing on a folder in GitHub repository

Tags: github, git-merge

I am new to GitHub and I don't know much of the things. Can anyone guide me on this and also the sources to learn to use GitHub in a better way..[I have deleted a file manually after entering it through git bash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0L0w.png) and
[Merge branch thing appearing here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8r3B.png)

I have tried to revert the commit but it hasn't done much.